# Can I prevent record deletions in Access?

Tags: ms-access

I have an access database with a table.  This table keeps getting records deleted, and I can't seem to find where the delete command is coming from.  Can I simply protect the records in some way so that NO ONE can delete them?

Comment: If it's an MDB, you could try securing the data and removing DELETE permission on that table from all the users and using RWOP queries for any deletes. If it's an ACCDB, there's no way to prevent deletions in a table.

Comment: It is an mdb.  How would I go about removing delete permissions?

Comment: You have to read the security white paper, run the security wizard and follow all the instructions to the letter. You can then edit the security settings of your tables and remove delete permissions. But then you'll need for each table where your app will be deleting records a corresponding saved QueryDef that is defined to run with owner permissions (RWOP), and you'll need to make the owner of those queries a user that has full delete permission on the underlying tables.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could introduce key constraints, but I really believe that you should know what's actually going on there first.

Comment: How would I go about putting in key constraints?

Comment: e.g. referencing these rows from within other table by introducing a foreign key, but as I said this is not the right solution but understanding what's going on there and acting accordingly.

Comment: I understand, but this isn't SQL Server, so I can't use Profiler.  How can I track down the delete command source?

Comment: I guess you should start by checking all queries / procedures and make sure that none causes you trouble. If you have an app that uses this DB indirectly, it's a bit more complex: you have to analyze that as well.

Comment: Well, I've found that some other Access .mdb is linking to this table, deleting the record, and trying to re-add it with additional information.  I'm modifying the vba code which does the delete-insert and changing it to update.  We'll see if that makes a difference.

Comment: You should tell whoever is responsible for that other MDB to stop doing that. That's by far the simplest solution.